# about Amazon SimpleDB, Select function

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-simpledb

I use these codes to connect SimpleDB and query data.
I can run the query in SQL Scrap Book, and the result is OK.
But when I run it in Eclipse, I got error message:

```
"12-18 22:01:57.401: I/com.amazonaws.request(402): Received error response: Status Code: 400, AWS Request ID: d68b7fcc-cd4a-7def-602c-96ad189d8fcf, AWS Error Code: NoSuchDomain, AWS Error Message: The specified domain does not exist."
```

Do you have any idea of that?

```
//1. Creating a SimpleDB Client
AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials( ACCESS_KEY_ID, SECRET_KEY );
AmazonSimpleDBClient sdbClient = new AmazonSimpleDBClient( credentials);        

//2. Select
String nextToken = null;
SelectRequest selectRequest = new SelectRequest( "select * from mydomain" ).withConsistentRead( true );
selectRequest.setNextToken( nextToken );        
SelectResult response = sdbClient.select( selectRequest );
nextToken = response.getNextToken();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to specify server region end point before requesting data for domain. Amazon Simple DB supports 7 region ends points.

Region, Endpoint

```
"US-East(Northern Virginia)", "sdb.amazonaws.com"
"EU(Ireland)", "sdb.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"
"US-West(Northern California)", "sdb.us-west-1.amazonaws.com"
"Asia Pacific(Singapore)", "sdb.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com"
"Asia Pacific(Tokyo)", "sdb.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com"
"US West(Oregon)", "sdb.us-west-2.amazonaws.com"
"South America(Sao Paulo)", "sdb.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com"
```

**How to set region end point**

```
BasicAWSCredentials basicAWSCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(sAccessKey, sSecretKey);
AmazonSimpleDBClient amazonSimpleDBClient = new AmazonSimpleDBClient(basicAWSCredentials);
amazonSimpleDBClient.setEndpoint(Endpoint);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks man! I just figured it out myself.
Here's whole code:

```
//1. Creating a SimpleDB Client
AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials( ACCESS_KEY, SECRET_KEY );
AmazonSimpleDBClient sdbClient = new AmazonSimpleDBClient( credentials);
sdbClient.setEndpoint("sdb.us-west-1.amazonaws.com"); // to define Data Center Region

//2. Select
String nextToken = null;
SelectRequest selectRequest = new SelectRequest( "select * from myDomain" ).withConsistentRead( true );
selectRequest.setNextToken( nextToken );        
SelectResult response = sdbClient.select( selectRequest );
nextToken = response.getNextToken();
```